# Reusable table component with Reactjs and material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came from `Vue.js` `Vuetify.js` background.`Vuetify.js` has  [v-data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#usage) component.

Simply we pass headers and items to generate a nice table.

```
 <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
  ></v-data-table>
```

If we want to add a button, image, or something like that to a table cell
What we do is

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" >
            <template v-slot:item.images="{ item }">
              <v-img
                v-if="item.images"
                max-width="150px"
                :src="item.images"
                contain
              ></v-img>
            </template>
           
            <template v-slot:item.update="{ item }">
              <v-btn
                @click="
                  $router.replace({
                    path: '/create-product',
                    query: { id: item.id },
                  })
                "
              >
                <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
              </v-btn></template
            >
          </v-data-table>
```

This is very clean and easy.

In React.js also I could achieve the first thing using this

```js
export default function ReusableTable({ headers, items }) {
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item>
        <Card>
          <CardContent>
            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
              <Table>
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    {headers.map((header, i) => (
                      <TableCell key={i}>{header.text.toUpperCase()}</TableCell>
                    ))}
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>{' '}
                <TableBody>
                  {items.map((item, i) => (
                    <TableRow key={i}>
                      {headers.map(({ value }) => (
                        <TableCell key={value}>{item[value]}</TableCell>
                      ))}
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Here also I pass the headers and items.
**I want to display buttons, links, images, chips (UI) for certain columns in the table. How do I achieve that in the React world?**

If I further explain, I want to pass items array (array of object). Object's imageSRC property should render with an `img` tag. Something like that.

Comment: Create custom `<TableCell>` components that mimic your Vuetify templates. To conditionally render them use standard if statements that return the respective custom table cell implementation (image or button). [Condtional Rendering Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: @RandyCasburn isn't there another way to do this? Because I already use this if conditions way. But this doesn't create a reuseable component. We have to hard code it to the component.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. This is conditionally rendering an image tag if there is an `item.images` as stated in your question. Next it will render a Material Button if `item.update` exists. Alternatively, it simply renders the `item[value]`.

Here is abbreviated code:

```js
export default function ReusableTable({ headers, items }) {
  const dynamicRender = (item, value)=>{
    if(item && item.images){
      return <img src=`${item.images}`/>
    } else if(item && item.update){
      return <Button href="/create-product">Link</Button>
    } else {
      return item[value];
    }
  }
  return (
    <TableBody>
      {items.map((item, i) => (
        <TableRow key={i}>
          {headers.map(({ value }) => (
            <TableCell key={value}>{dynamicRender(item, value)}</TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </TableBody>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```js
import React from "react";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";

import { getSlots } from 'helpers/Slots'

const BaseTable = ({ headers, items, children, ...otherProps }) => {
  const [actions] = getSlots(['actions'], children)

  const tableConfig = {
    size: "small",
  }

  const rowConfig = {
    ...otherProps,
  }

  const dynamicRenderer = (item, value) => {
    if (value === 'actions') {
      return children(item)
    } else {
      return item[value]
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table {...tableConfig}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow {...rowConfig}>
              {headers.map((header, i) => (
                <TableCell key={i}>{header.label}</TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {items.map((item, i) => (
              <TableRow key={i} {...rowConfig}>
                {headers.map(({ value }) => (
                  <TableCell key={value}>{dynamicRenderer(item, value)}</TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      </>
  )
}
export default BaseTable
```

Then added helpers

```js
import React from "react";

const Slot = ({ children })  => <>{children}</>

const getSlots = ( names, children) =>  {
  return names.map(name => {
    let slot = null;
    React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
      if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
        return;
      }
      if (child.type === Slot && (child.props).name === name) {
        slot = React.cloneElement(child);
      }
    });
    return slot;
  });
}

export { Slot, getSlots }
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

import BaseTable from 'helpers/Table'
import { Slot } from 'helpers/Slots'

import PencilBoxOutline from 'mdi-react/PencilBoxIcon'
import DeleteOutline from 'mdi-react/DeleteIcon'

const headers = [
  {value: 'name', label: 'Name'},
  {value: 'age', label: 'Age'},
  {value: 'gender', label: 'Gender'},
  {value: 'registeredDate', label: 'Date of Registration'},
  {value: 'requirements', label: 'Semester Requirements'},
  {value: 'percentage', label: 'Percentage (%)'},
  {value: 'actions', label: 'Actions'},
]

const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    requirements: 'Pay at least 50% ',
    percentage: '10%',
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 30,
    registeredDate: "2021/10/30",
    gender: "Male"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    requirements: 'Just go with it',
    percentage: '50%',
    name: "Jane Doe",
    age: 40,
    registeredDate: "2021/10/30",
    gender: "Female"
  },
]

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={4}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" spacing={2}>
          <Grid item></Grid>
          <Grid item sm={9}></Grid>
        </Grid>
        <BaseTable headers={headers} items={items}>
         {(item) => (
          <Slot name="actions">
            <PencilBoxOutline onClick={(item) => onOpenDialog(item)}/>
            <DeleteOutline onClick={(item) => onDelete(item)} />
          </Slot>
          )}
        </BaseTable>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default Test
```